# How do I navigate to another screen in React js using href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying link a button to another screen within my application using href. For some reason when press the href it takes me to the top of the same screen and to the screen I want to go.

How would i do that?

Here is my screen that has a href I'm using to link to another screen

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CarDetail from './carDetail';

export class Services extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <a
        href="./carDetail"
        title="Car Detailing"
        data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1">
        <div className="hover-text">
          <h4>Car Detailing</h4>
        </div>
        <img
          src="img/portfolio/carSmall.jpg"
          className="img-responsive"
          alt="Car Detail"
        />
      </a>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my screen i want the user to go to when they press the href

```
import React from "react";
export default function CarDetail() {
  return (
    <header id="header">
      <div className="intro">
        <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 intro-text">
          <h1>We offer a wide assortment of options for Mobile Detailing </h1>
          <p>How it Works</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: For routing you could use https://reactrouter.com/.